# Добавление базы данных MS SQL Server в Solution и git

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, git, github

в общем пишу веб приложение ASP.NET, ну и у меня есть потребность залить его на GitHub, проблема заключается в том что к проекту подключена база данных MS SQL Server, и без БД приложение естественно работать не будет.

Допустим у меня есть друг/партнер с которым мы вместе решили разрабатывать это веб приложение.

Насколько я знаю, в ASP.NET есть папочка App_Data, где как написано в книжечке с которой я ознакомился, должны желательно как раз и лежать БД, ну как туда запихать БД я не знаю и вообще стоит ли это делать тоже не знаю.

Я использую Visual Studio 2019, MS SQL Server 2017.

Я хотел бы узнать как эту проблему решить, желательно без издевок и подробно, или есть какой то другой путь решения этой проблемы, в общем ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если база данных имеет сложную структуру с кучей таблиц, представлений, хранимых процедур и так далее, и при этом постоянно модифицируется, причём разными людьми, то самым правильным решением будет SQL Server Data Tools или сокрощённо SSDT. Это особый вид проекта Visual Studio для баз данных. Там в виде скриптов описывается струкура всей БД. Потом из этого проекта можно делать различные скрипты на изменения в БД. Но самое главное, эту структуру можно удобно хранить в git. У вас будет человеческая история изменений. Кроме того, данные в этой структуре не хранятся, так что объём получается небольшой (это важно, ведь git будет хранить все версии файла).

Но если у вас в БД пара таблиц, которые в ближайшей перспективе не изменятся, то есть ещё такие варианты:

- Бэкап базы
- Data-tier application
- Скрипт на создание БД

Наполнение каких-то служебынх таблиц, типа словарей, во всех случаях можно так же описать скриптом.

Сама тема с SSDT слишком обширна, чтобы её просто так тут описывать.

Comment: Спасибо, мне понравилась тема с SSDT, я подразобрался и это лучший способ для меня, так что спасибо)

Answer (score 4):

> Насколько я знаю, в ASP.NET есть папочка App_Data, где как написано в
>   книжечке с которой я ознакомился, должны желательно как раз и лежать
>   БД

Они вовсе не обязательно должны там лежать. Более того обычно файлы БД и сам MS SQL находятся на отдельном сервере, с которым прикладное ПО контактирует только через клиентскую библиотеку.

Существует 2 способа решить Вашу задачу без особых трудозатрат:

- Сделать бэкап и приложить файл с ним к репозиторию (желательно с инструкцией по развёртыванию);
- Если используется EntityFramework и в целом платформа не очень старая, перейти на миграции. Тогда БД будет подниматься и обновляться по команде в консоли или автоматически (если Вы напишите соответствующий скрипт).

Последний подход более современный и простой в развёртывании (особенно со скриптом).